# Rails - Attribute is nil when using form_for helper method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication

Brand new to rails here. I'm trying to implement a user authentication system using a password and a hashing algorithm. Now when I try to create a new user, the password attribute of the user is always nil.

Here is my User/new view:

```
    <% @page_title = 'New Users' %>
    <div class="user new">
      <h2>Create User</h2>

      <%= form_for(:user, :url => {:action => 'create'}) do |f| %>

        <%= render(:partial => 'form', :locals => {:f => f} ) %>

        <div class="form-buttons">
          <%= submit_tag('Create User') %>
        </div>

      <% end %>
    </div>
    <%= link_to 'Back', users_path %>
```

And my partial layout _form:

```
<% if @user.errors.any? %>
      <div id="error_explanation">
        <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>

    <ul>
    <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>

<table summary="Admin user form fields">
  <tr>
    <th><%= f.label(:first_name) %></th>
    <td><%= f.text_field(:first_name) %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th><%= f.label(:last_name) %></th>
    <td><%= f.text_field(:last_name) %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th><%= f.label(:email) %></th>
    <td><%= f.text_field(:email) %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th><%= f.label(:password) %></th>
    <td><%= f.text_field(:password) %></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

However, by the time we get to the controller, @user.password is always nil. Why isn't the value of the :password form being brought through? Code from the controller:

```
 def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    flash[:notice] = "Password: " + @user.password #ALWAYS NIL

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Password is attr_accessor in the model. Here is the model code:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessor :password #not value in database, only in model
  validates_length_of :password, :within => 6..25, :on => :create

  before_save :create_hashed_password
  after_save :clear_password

  def self.hash_with_salt(password= "", salt="")
    Digest::SHA1.hexdigest("Put #{salt} on the #{password}")
  end

  #makes a salt for encription using the user's email (unique) and time (random)
  def self.make_salt(email="")
    Digest::SHA1.hexdigest("Use #{email} with #{Time.now} 2 make salt")
  end

  #will return user if login is successful else returns fasle
  def self.authenticate(email="", password="")
    user = User.find_by_email(email)
    if user && user.password_match?(password)
      return user
    else
      return false
    end
  end


  #The same password string with the same hash method should always generate
  #the same hashed_password
  def password_match?(password="")
    hashed_password == User.hash_with_salt(password, salt)
  end


  private

  def create_hashed_password
    #Whenever :password has a value, hashing is needed

    unless password.blank?
      self.salt = User.make_salt(username) if salt.blank?
      self.hashed_password = User.hash_with_salt(password, salt)
    end
  end

  def clear_password
    self.password = nil
  end

end
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your create action change this:

`@user = User.new(user_params)`

to

`@user = User.new(params[:user])`